# how to configure aws ec2 with eclipse through pem file

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, pem, toolkit

I have spend a good time in googling and didn't found any way to configure AWS EC2 with eclipse through pem file.
Already installed AWS Toolkit.
But i don't have access to create access key and secret key.

EDIT:
I have a project hosted in AWS EC2 instance(ubuntu) and i want to access project files in eclipse so that i can make changes in code or debugging the code.
Like we configure through ssh in eclipse and then able to access code and terminal both.

Comment: not sure what u mean by configure ec2 with eclipse.. PEM file is needed ONLY to SSH to EC2 instance.. Access key/secret key are used  to invoke different AWS Services from your EC2

Comment: Could you please Edit your question and provide more details about what you are trying to achieve, what you did, and what difficulties you encountered?

Comment: @john  i want to Configure EC2 Server Instances Using AWS Toolkit for Eclipse and also edited my question.

Comment: So, it really isn't specific to EC2 -- it appears that you want to know how to use Eclipse on one machine that can edit files stored on a remote machine.

Comment: @john sorry for delay response. you got me right, but only one thing is not any remote machine only EC2 instance.